# Sidekiq Job never ending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sidekiq

I had a simple process to do a #delete_all on a collection of 2700 objects.

27 minutes later and the job hasn't completed... last thing I have is

```
Performing DiscontinuedProductsJob from Sidekiq(default)
```

I'll be honest. I have no idea what this means. Is it still "working"?
 I am not sure what to do if it doesn't ever "end".

Comment: No, it's not possible that it would take 27 minutes to perform that operation. Is your Sidekiq server running? Do you have redis installed and configured?

Comment: It finally completed after 1700 seconds... I am so confused by this.